# How to simplify query boolean data in sqlite?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have query that count the headcount base on assigned letter code per day.

I've used 3 tables;

```
TABLE :status as st
+----------------+---------------+--------+
| ID | status_name | status_code | status |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+
| 1  | Available   | A           | true   |
+------------------+-------------+--------+
| 2  | HalfDay     | H           | true   |
+------------------+-------------+--------+
| 3  | On Leave    | OL          | true   |            
+------------------+-------------+--------+
| 4  | Restday     | R           | true   |            
+------------------+-------------+--------+
| 5  | Vacation    | V           | true   |            
+------------------+-------------+--------+

TABLE : employees as e
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| EmployeeName | Site  | Shift | Team | JobTitle |
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| Steve        | Bldg1 | Night | N1   | Doctor   |
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| Dave         | Bldg1 | Night | N2   | Nurse    | 
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| Jack         | Bldg1 | Night | N2   | Nurse    |
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| Jacob        | Bldg2 | Day   | D1   | Doctor   |
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| Noah         | Bldg2 | Day   | D2   | Nurse    | 
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| MAX          | Bldg2 | Day   | D2   | Nurse    | 
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+

TABLE : schedule as sc
+----------+-------+-------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| JobsType | Site  | Shift | Team | SUN | MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI | SAT |
+----------+-------+-------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Doctor   | Bldg1 | Night | N1   | A   | H   | A   | A   | OL  | A   | A   |
+----------+-------+-------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Nurse    | Bldg1 | Night | N2   | A   | H   | H   | A   | A   | A   | A   |
+----------+-------+-------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Doctor   | Bldg2 | Day   | D1   | H   | A   | H   | H   | A   | A   | OL  |
+----------+-------+-------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Nurse    | Bldg1 | Night | N2   | A   | H   | H   | A   | A   | A   | A   |
+----------+-------+-------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

By using this query:

```
SELECT st.status_name, st.status_code
 , sum(sc.SUN = st.status_code) AS SUN
 , sum(sc.MON = st.status_code) AS MON
 , sum(sc.TUE = st.status_code) AS TUE
 , sum(sc.WED = st.status_code) AS WED
 , sum(sc.THU = st.status_code) AS THU
 , sum(sc.FRI = st.status_code) AS FRI
 , sum(sc.SAT = st.status_code) AS SAT
FROM status AS st
JOIN schedule AS sc ON st.status_code IN (sc.SUN, sc.MON, sc.TUE, sc.WED
                                        , sc.THU, sc.FRI, sc.SAT)
JOIN employees AS e ON sc.JobsType = e.JobTitle AND sc.Site = e.Site
                   AND sc.Shift = e.Shift AND sc.Team = e.Team
GROUP BY st.status_name, st.status_code
ORDER BY st.status_name, st.status_code;
```

I achieved this result:

```
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| STATUS TYPES | SUN | MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI | SAT |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Available    | 5   | 4   | 4   | 5   | 5   | 6   | 5   |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| HalfDay      | 1   | 5   | 5   | 1   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| On Leave     | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0   | 1   |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Restday      | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Vacation     | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------

Now I'm having a hard time on how to work with a boolean value to reference.

Here are my tables;

```
TABLE: SkillList (1/0 = true/false)
+----------+--------+
| Skills   | Status |
+----------+--------+
| Skill_1  | 1      | 
+----------+--------+
| Skill_2  | 1      |
+----------+--------+
| Skill_3  | 1      | 
+----------+--------+
| Skill_4  | 1      |
+----------+--------+
| Skill_5  | 0      |
+----------+--------+

TABLE: Skill Available (1/0 = true/false)
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Username | Skill_1| Skill_2 | Skill_3 | Skill_4 |
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Steve    | 1      | 1       | 1       | 1       |
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Dave     | 1      | 0       | 1       | 0       | 
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Jack     | 1      | 1       | 0       | 0       | 
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Jacob    | 1      | 1       | 0       | 0       | 
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
Note: Zero represents users that doesn't have that skill.

TABLE: Attendance (1/0 = true/false)
+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Username | Site  | Shift | SUN | MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI | SAT |
+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Steve    | Bldg1 | Night | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 0   | 0   |
+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Dave     | Bldg1 | Night | 1   | 1   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 1   | 1   |
+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Jack     | Bldg2 | Day   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 1   |
+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Jacob    | Bldg1 | Night | 1   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   |
+----------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
Note: Zero represents restday.
```

By using the tables above how could I achieved this result that count available user per day base on there skill?

```
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| SkillList | SUN | MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI | SAT |
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Skill_1   | 4   | 3   | 2   | 2   | 3   | 3   | 3   |
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Skill_2   | 3   | 3   | 1   | 1   | 2   | 2   | 2   |
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Skill_3   | 2   | 2   | 1   | 0   | 2   | 1   | 1   |
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Skill_4   | 1   | 1   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0   | 0   |
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Skill_5   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: If your `"Skill Available"` table was a normal many-to-many junction table with a `(userid, skillid)` layout it'd be pretty simple...

Comment: Also, your expected results don't mesh up with your sample data - take `Skill_4` for example... only one person has it and they work 5 days, but you only have it listed for 3 days?

Comment: could you write  the connections between tables to avoid any confusion

Answer (score 3):

SQL databases are all about modelling *relationships* between data, and there are well established ways to do so. In this case, you have *many* users, each of which may have *many* skills, - a **many to many relationship**. The way to model this is known by [many names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity), but I prefer **junction table**. Basically, instead of a table with a column for each skill and a row for each user, have a table of `(skill id, user id)` pairs with a row for each particular combination. If a user doesn't have a skill, no row with that particular combination exists.

Setting up some example tables from your data to demonstrate the idea:

```
CREATE TABLE SkillList(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, skill TEXT);
INSERT INTO SkillList VALUES
  (1, 'Skill 1'), (2, 'Skill 2'), (3, 'Skill 3'), (4, 'Skill 4'), (5, 'Skill 5');

CREATE TABLE Attendance(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT UNIQUE
                      , site TEXT, shift Text, SUN INTEGER, MON INTEGER
                      , TUE INTEGER, WED INTEGER, THU INTEGER, FRI INTEGER
                      , SAT INTEGER);
INSERT INTO Attendance VALUES
 (1, 'Steve', 'Bldg1', 'Night', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 (2, 'Dave', 'Bldg1', 'Night', 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
 (3, 'Jack', 'Bldg2', 'Day', 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
 (4, 'Jacob', 'Bldg1', 'Night', 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1);

CREATE TABLE SkillsAvailable(skill_id INTEGER REFERENCES SkillList(id)
                           , user_id INTEGER REFERENCES Attendance(id)
                           , PRIMARY KEY(skill_id, user_id)) WITHOUT ROWID;
INSERT INTO SkillsAvailable VALUES
 (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4),
 (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4),
 (3, 1), (3, 2),
 (4, 1);
```

will let you join the `SkillList` and `Attendance` tables together by putting `SkillsAvailable` in the middle:

```
SELECT sl.skill AS "Skill Name"
     , ifnull(sum(a.SUN), 0) AS SUN
     , ifnull(sum(a.MON), 0) AS MON
     , ifnull(sum(a.TUE), 0) AS TUE
     , ifnull(sum(a.WED), 0) AS WED
     , ifnull(sum(a.THU), 0) AS THU
     , ifnull(sum(a.FRI), 0) AS FRI
     , ifnull(sum(a.SAT), 0) AS SAT
FROM SkillList AS sl
LEFT OUTER JOIN SkillsAvailable AS sa ON sl.id = sa.skill_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Attendance AS a ON sa.user_id = a.id
GROUP BY sl.id
ORDER BY sl.skill;
```

Outer joins are used so that skills that aren't used by anyone still show up in the results, which are:

```
Skill Name  SUN         MON         TUE         WED         THU         FRI         SAT
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
Skill 1     4           3           2           2           3           3           3
Skill 2     3           2           2           2           2           2           2
Skill 3     2           2           1           1           2           1           1
Skill 4     1           1           1           1           1           0           0
Skill 5     0           0           0           0           0           0           0
```

---

Besides making this sort of calculations more complex, your current database layout has other issues with the `"Skills Available"` table - adding a new skill means adding a new column, removing a skill you don't care about means either deleting that column - a very convoluted process in sqlite - or having unused ones hanging around wasting some space. It makes for a fragile, over complicated design. Better to play to the strengths of relational databases.