# How to query the sum of each person's availability base on their skill

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm using sqlite, I've setup three tables.

```
Table for list of skills this can be expand.
+----+----------+
| ID | Skills   |
+----+----------+
| 1  | Swimming |
| 2  | Running  |
| 3  | Boxing   |
| 4  | Dancing  |
| 5  | Singing  |
+----+----------+
```

Table for availability of each person. 0 represents the person is not available.

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Names | SUN | MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI | SAT |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Mark  | 0   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 0   | (MON-FRI)
| Robin | 0   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 0   | (MON-FRI)
| James | 0   | 0   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | (TUE-SAT)
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Table for each person skill possess. 1/0 is a boolean value.

```
+-------+----------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| Names | Swimming | Running | Boxing | Dancing | Singing |
+-------+----------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| Mark  | 1        | 1       | 1      | 1       | 1       |
| Robin | 1        | 1       | 1      | 1       | 1       | 
| James | 1        | 1       | 1      | 1       | 0       | 
+-------+----------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
```

---

By using the tables above how could I achieved this result to sum each person's availability base on their skill.

```
Expected Results:
+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Skills   | SUN | MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI | SAT |
+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Swimming | 0   | 2   | 3   | 3   | 3   | 3   | 1   |
| Running  | 0   | 2   | 3   | 3   | 3   | 3   | 1   |
| Boxing   | 0   | 2   | 3   | 3   | 3   | 3   | 1   |
| Dancing  | 0   | 2   | 3   | 3   | 3   | 3   | 1   |
| Singing  | 0   | 2   | 3   | 3   | 3   | 3   | 0   |
+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Someone asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56623726/how-to-simplify-query-boolean-data-in-sqlite) yesterday. Same advice as I gave there; fix your database design.

Comment: Got it! but what if these are the only tables that I can be used? Is there other way or workaround?